# Best framework to develop cross platform UI on desktop which is also easy to automate for UI test cases

Tags: user-interface, automation, cross-platform, desktop-application

Best framework to develop cross platform UI on desktop which is also easy to automate for UI test cases.
Currently the application is in JAVA but automating the UI is a big task and doesn't work seamlessly for all UI cases.
Automation tool used for Java is abbot.
Can someone recommend a better option if any for UI which has good automation possibilities and needs to work on win and linux.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is a good option for UI development, but not sure about automation. There are not so many open-source tools for desktop UI automation. Most of them work on one operating system only. Our small community is working to make [pywinauto GUI automation library working on Linux](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/328) but there is no deadline yet so it's Windows only for now. You can also find several Linux-only and MacOS-only tools so that seemless automation is not possible without expensive monsters like TestComplete, Squish or UFT.

P.S. [List & rating of open-source tools](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings). Some of them (Sikuli, Lackey, PyAutoGUI) use image recognition (it's not very reliable but cross-platform).